# Update treeview with addition of new children/root

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview, observablecollection

I am using `WPF TreeView` with `MVVM` pattern. I manage to bind it properly using `ObservableCollection`. But when I am adding new items to it the TreeView does not update.

```
<TreeView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path= AccountTreeObs}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>

ObservableCollection<IAccountsTreeViewModel> AccountTreeObs { get; set; }
```

Another code is normal button command which adds root accounts and fetches data again to assign above property again. But the view apparently does not update.

Comment: What type is Children? If its not an ObservableCollection, you need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and call `OnPropertyChanged()`: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/208833-using-the-inotifypropertychanged-functionality/ Same goes for your Name-propety.

Comment: children are of same type. its basically a recursive class of same type. am i misssing something.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is that your ViewModel does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged. If you could show your ViewModel I could tell you for sure. Until then this is the best answer I can give.